# MySQL Arbitrary Ordering Of Group By

Tags: mysql

I have a SQL query the looks like

```
SELECT Fruit, COUNT(*) FROM Table1 GROUP BY Fruit
```

It Returns

Grape      8
Apple      2
Peach      9
Orange     6
Banana     5

I do NOT wish to sort alphabetically.

I want it in this order

Banana
Apple
Orange
Peach
Grape

I cant seem to get they Syntax right on a case stamens.....Help!

Comment: Why do you want to sort it in that order? You're going to have to come up with *some* kind of rule.

Comment: Add a new integer column to Table1.  Call it `SortOrder`, set the values as needed then sort by it when selecting.

Comment: I would like to use a  CASE Fruit WHEN 'Banana' THEN 1.... Stamanet but its getting lost in the GROUP BY.

Comment: I dont know how a sort order column would work here.  Note that I am using GROUP BY   (There are 30 Records in this example!)

Comment: I don't understand this question at all. The example output provided is not alphabetically sorted, and I don't see the pattern in the second set. What do you want to accomplish?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use FIELD() function:

```
SELECT Fruit, COUNT(*)
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Fruit
ORDER BY FIELD(Fruit, 'Banana','Apple','Orange','Peach','Grape')
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `CASE` in an `ORDER BY` clause to put the data in an order that you want:

```
SELECT Fruit, COUNT(*) Total
FROM Table1 
GROUP BY Fruit
order by 
  case fruit 
    when 'banana' then 1
    when 'apple' then 2
    when 'orange' then 3
    when 'peach' then 4
    when 'grape' then 5 
    else 6 end;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7cdc1/1)